# не работает protoc

Tags: golang, grpc, google-protobuf, protoc

Мой $GOPATH = /home/<user>/work

Структура проекта:

```
~/gop/gRPC/
-----------src/
---------------main.go
---------------person.proto
```

Содержимое person.proto:

```
syntax= "proto3";
package main;

message Person{
    string name =1;
    int32 age = 2;
}
```

Содержимое main.go:

```
package main

func main() {

}
```

В консоли vscode находясь в каталоге проекта запускаю:

```
protoc --go_out=. *.proto
```

В ответ получаю:

```
  protoc-gen-go: unable to determine Go import path for "person.proto"

Please specify either:
        • a "go_package" option in the .proto source file, or
        • a "M" argument on the command line.

See https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated#package for more information.

--go_out: protoc-gen-go: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

Этот пример брал [здеcь](https://tutorialedge.net/golang/go-protocol-buffer-tutorial/) в видео.
Не понимаю что я делаю не так. В видео все работает без дополнительных настроек. Мне нужно чтобы формировались файлы go со структурой заданной в .proto.

Comment: надо запускать из папки src

Comment: https://pastebin.com/WBpv1wyM все работает

Comment: @SeniorPomidor
тоже ошибка 

`protoc-gen-go: unable to determine Go import path for "person.proto"

Please specify either:
        • a "go_package" option in the .proto source file, or
        • a "M" argument on the command line.

See https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated#package for more information.

--go_out: protoc-gen-go: Plugin failed with status code 1.`

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение
Нужно в файл .proto  импортировать путь к пакету .go. В моем случае это строчка в файл .proto

```
option go_package = "./";
```

в итоге файл .proto стал таким

```
syntax= "proto3";
package main;
option go_package = "./";

message Person{
    string name =1;
    int32 age = 2;
}
```